# Calling API from Apache Cordova app not working (Android)

Tags: android, api, cordova, whitelist

I am working on an Apache Cordova app that gets stuck trying to load a map. It works in android 4.2.2 but not working on more recent versions 7.0.0/7.1.1.

I try to call it from my index.html file with the next line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.cercalia.com/api/cercalia.js?key=[key]&theme=red"></script>
```

Also I created a test file within my JS folder with the code from the API online and it works perfectly.

I suspect that the `whitelist` plugin might not be working properly.

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I just had to add the next meta tag on the `index.html` head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

This will load the map correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Internet Permission

Go to app -> src -> main -> AndroidManifest.xml.

Add following code

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.java2blog.helloworldapp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".HelloWorldActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so I found the problem.

```
window.cordova.plugins
```

was undefined. This was a standard or common place to put plugins in previous cordova versions but didn't get defined in corvoda 7.

I found this line of code was causing the issue:

```
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.firebase && window.cordova.plugins.firebase.analytics) {
```

I have no idea why this was showing a `-` in the error message!